# Pentaho Data Inegration - Multiple Excel File Inputs Loading

Tags: excel, pentaho, business-intelligence, pentaho-spoon

I've been using Spoon as a tool to complete a project. One of the requirements is to load multiple Excel files, that have the same format (sheets), in order to output it to a Table Output.

However the number of Excel Files has to be variable (requirement) but they are located on the same folder. Which step(s) allows to load all the Excel files that are on a folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Microsoft Excel input` step support reading all files in a folder, or some based on regular expressions. You can also read all files including subfolders.

[image: microsoft excel input step]